# How do I remove rows from a data.frame where two specific columns have missing values?

Tags: r

Say I write the following code to produce a dataframe:

```
name <- c("Joe","John","Susie","Mack","Mo","Curly","Jim")
age <- c(1,2,3,NaN,4,5,NaN)
DOB <- c(10000, 12000, 16000, NaN, 18000, 20000, 22000)
DOB <- as.Date(DOB, origin = "1960-01-01")
trt <- c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(name, age, DOB, trt)
```

that looks like this:

```
   name age        DOB trt
1   Joe   1 1987-05-19   0
2  John   2 1992-11-08   1
3 Susie   3 2003-10-22   1
4  Mack NaN       <NA>   2
5    Mo   4 2009-04-13   2
6 Curly   5 2014-10-04   1
7   Jim NaN 2020-03-26   1
```

How would I be able to remove rows where both age and DOB have missing values for the row? For example, I'd like a new dataframe (df2) to look like this:

```
   name age        DOB trt
1   Joe   1 1987-05-19   0
2  John   2 1992-11-08   1
3 Susie   3 2003-10-22   1
5    Mo   4 2009-04-13   2
6 Curly   5 2014-10-04   1
7   Jim NaN 2020-03-26   1
```

I've tried the following code, but it deleted too many rows:

```
df2 <- df[!(is.na(df$age)) & !(is.na(df$DOB)), ]
```

In SAS, I would just write 
`WHERE missing(age) ge 1 AND missing(DOB) ge 1` in a DATA step, but obviously R has different syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your attempt would work if you changed to something like `df[(is.na(df$age)) + (is.na(df$DOB)) < 2, ]`

Comment: `df[rowSums(is.na(df)) < 2L,]`? This produces your desired output. `rowSums(is.na(df))` returns a vector with the number of NAs per row of df, in this case `[1] 0 0 0 2 0 0 1`. This is used to subset df.

Comment: @rawr That works! I don't understand the syntax though. Wouldn't a row where both `df$age` and `df$DOB` were missing be equal to 2, rather than `df[(is.na(df$age)) + (is.na(df$DOB)) < 2, ]` ?

Comment: @beginneR that may work, but what if there were rows where two of the column values were missing, but not the specific columns I was interested in (i.e., `df$age` and `df$DOB`)? Also, could you refer me to a document explaining the use of the `L` modifier/suffix in your example?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were only interested in those two columns or all. If you want only those two (and they are the second and third) you can do `df[rowSums(is.na(df[2:3])) < 2L,]` or `df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("age", "DOB")])) < 2L,]`. The `L` is used to make sure the number is an integer - but you don't _need_ to use it here.

Comment: the inequality will evaluate to a logical and will keep any rows that fit the criteria, namely less than two NAs

Comment: You could also use `df[!is.na(df$age) | !is.na(df$DOB),]` (either both or one of the columns should be _not_ NA).

Comment: I see some nice answers here, why everything is comments though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove those rows where two columns (age and DOB) have more than 1 NA (which would mathematically mean that there could only be 2 NAs in such a case), you can do for example:

```
df[!is.na(df$age) | !is.na(df$DOB),]
```

which means that either both or one of the columns should be *not* NA, or

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[2:3])) < 2L,]
```

which means that the sum of NAs in columns 2 and 3 should be less than 2 (hence, 1 or 0) or very similar:

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df[c("age", "DOB")])) < 2L,]
```

And of course there's other options, like what @rawr provided in the comments.

And to better understand the subsetting, check this:

```
rowSums(is.na(df[2:3]))
#[1] 0 0 0 2 0 0 1

rowSums(is.na(df[2:3])) < 2L
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close

```
df[!(is.na(df$age) & is.na(df$DOB)), ]
```

or

```
df[!is.na(df$age) | !is.na(df$DOB), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be easier:

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- drop_na(df, c("age", "DOB"))
```