# How to exclude subjects with a specific proportion of NA in two columns

Tags: r, na, subject

I have a dataset with columns for subject id, segment (1-42) and two columns with amplitudes (microvolt, t-transformed). The research aim is to compare Scoring/Quantification Methods of Electromyogram data scored manually vs. automatically. That's why there are two columns with the amplitudes.
My goal for now is to exclude participants (column "vp") whose proportion of NA's is ≥ 20% in either of the two columns. Alternatively it would also be enough to print the subject id of the subjects who fulfil the criteria. I had the idea to use an if-else function, but can't wrap my head around how to define the criteria.

Here are the first rows of my dataset; there are 42 rows of each subject.

```r
structure(list(vp = c("AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU", "AD_001_B_NPU"), seg = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9), t_amp_manual = c(70.6,81.4,58.1, 78.1, 59.2, 55.1, 55.1, 62.2,59.7), t_amp_automatic = c(73.7, NA, 59.8, 82.9, 62.7, NA, 53.6, 65.0, 63.3), (row.names = c("vp", "seg", "t_amp_manual","t_amp_automatic"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your example throws an error: `"error: unexpected symbol in "dput(npu_Kopie[1:10, c(1,2,3,4)]) structure"`

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post; I've just fixed the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove rows from a data.frame where two specific columns have missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434556/how-do-i-remove-rows-from-a-data-frame-where-two-specific-columns-have-missing-v)

Comment: @denis that seems like a pretty different problem - OP wants to remove entire groups based on a percentage of missing values. Your link is removing rows with a simpler row-wise condition.

Answer (score 1):

Untested because I couldn't get your data working, but this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
npu_Kopie %>%
  ## assuming `vp` is the "subject" column??
  group_by(vp) %>%   
  filter(
    mean(is.na(t_amp_manual)) < 0.2 & mean(is.na(t_amp_automatic)) < 0.2
  )
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to R. Does the "group_by" function work, since there are 42 rows for each subject and this data frame contains the data of all subjects?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much right. `group_by` is specific to the `dplyr` package and other functions in it - it doesn't work generally. But the idea is that it (behind the scenes) splits your data frame into pieces based on the unique values of the grouping column(s), applies data transformations on each piece individually, and then combines the data back together when you get the results. I'd highly recommend looking at some of the [dplyr vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cleanest code but it can probably solve your problem.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), b = c(NA,2,3,NA,5,NA), c = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), d = c(1,NA,NA,NA,5,6), e = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,6), f = c(1,NA,NA,NA,5,6))

for(i in 1:length(df[1,])){

 if(sum(is.na(df[,i]))/length(df[,i])<= 0.2){


 } else {

df <-  df[,-i]

}

}
```